# Maven plugin for merging pom.xml files

Tags: java, maven-2

We have a parent Maven project (agregator) and some daughter projects:

```
parent/
  child1/
  child2/
  ...
```

Now we want convert that structure to one project and we need to merge pom.xml files together. The problem is that projects have very complicated pom.xml files with many configurations (lifecycle phases, platform specific settings, goals, etc..) and long lists of dependencies. Manual merging will be complicated and error-prone.

Does someone know any Maven plugin for merging pom.xml files ?

Comment: you want to merge daughters? How would you merge source? Can you give me the use-case. Can't comprehend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the "shade" plugin can help: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html

Comment: How does this help?

Answer (score 1):

I have developed such one for my purposes, called uber-pom, it has been published in maven central 
https://github.com/raydac/uber-pom